# Getting the unique factors of a number recursively

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-2.x, factors

I have written the below code to get the unique factors. Please offer suggestions for better results.

```
#Python program to print out all ways to multiply smaller integers 
#that equal the original number, without repeating sets of factors



def print_factors_list(dividend, factorstring, predivisor):
"""This function takes a number and prints the factors"""


   divisor = dividend - 1
   #Looping to get the factors
   for i in range(divisor, 1, -1 ):

      if dividend % i != 0:
        continue

      if i > predivisor:
        continue
      #Get the quotient for the multipying number   
      quotient = dividend / i


      if quotient <= i:
         if quotient <= predivisor:
            print factorstring + str(i) + "*" + str(quotient)
      print_factors_list(quotient, str(factorstring) + str(i) + "*", i)




#Check if the number is greater than 0
def print_factors(x):
# Check if the number is greater than 0 
    if (x < 0):
        print "Enter a positive integer"
    #Check if the number is 0
    elif (x == 0):
        print "Enter a positive integer"
    #Go to the function print_factors_list for further evaluation
    else:
    #Print the default factors(the number itself and 1)
       print str(x) + "*" + str(1)
       print_factors_list(x, "", x )




#Take input from the user
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
#Call the function with the number given by the user
print_factors(num)
```

Comment: Your docstring is incorrectly indented; please fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative (and probably more efficient) approach would be to derive all prime factors (hint: you could use `divmod`) and then create each of the possible factorings from that (hint: you could use `itertools` `combinations`).

Some notes:

1. If  you extract prime factors from smallest to largest, the remainder will always either be prime or be a composite with a smallest prime factor greater than or equal to the last one found.
2. One can also use the fact that all of the prime numbers except 2 are odd numbers to step through quickly.
3. The largest possible prime factor of any integer \$n\$ may be discovered by examining no more than \$\sqrt{n}\$ potential factors.

You might want to peek at [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11317/prime-factorization-of-a-number?rq=1) for a Python-based prime factoring program.

### Getting all factors from prime factorization

Starting with an example 60, we can easily determine that its prime factorization `p = [2, 2, 3, 5]`.  Clearly, this is one possible factorization, which can easily be output in Python 3 as

```
print(*p, sep=' * ')
```

If you're using 2.6 or 2.7, you can still use this neat syntax, but you'll have to do this instead

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(*p, sep=' * ')
```

This prints:

```
2 * 2 * 3 * 5
```

So now all you need to do is create all possible unique lists of factors.  So for each two-factor combination, you could use this:

```
for i in itertools.permutations(p,len(p)):
    print(*[i[0],reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,i[1:])],sep=' * ')
```

That creates a list of all such two-factor combinations with exactly one prime factor, but they are not unique.  Because there is a repeated factor of 2 in the list, the product "2 * 30" is printed twice.  One way to handle this is to store each factor as it's used and suppress printing of non-unique factors.

Similarly, all non-unique 3-factor combinations with one prime factor:

```
for i in itertools.permutations(p,len(p)):
    print(*[i[0],i[1],reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,i[2:])],sep=' * ')
```

Or alternatively:

```
for i in itertools.permutations(p,len(p)):
    print(*(list(i[:2])+[reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,i[2:])]),sep=' * ')
```

This should give you enough of a clue as to how you might generate all possible factorizations.  A recursive approach is probably even better here.

Also, as an incidental note, factorings with 1 are typically omitted as trivial.

Comment: Your third point is incorrect.

Comment: @Edward - can you elaborate on prime factors as the factors are composite too? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Focusing on refactoring of your current idea rather than making any radical changes, you could:

1. note that we are only interested in divisors which are less than or equal to the predivisor, and adjust the `range`  to exclude all values of the divisor that don't satisfy this.
2. turn `print_factors_list` into a generator yielding all the lists of factors, and do all the actual printing in `print_factors`. This (along with a couple of other minor changes) makes the code more readable, in my view.

.

```
def get_factors_list(dividend, ceiling = float('infinity')):
    """ Yield all lists of factors where the largest is no larger than ceiling """
    for divisor in range(min(ceiling, dividend - 1), 1, -1):
        quotient, mod = divmod(dividend, divisor)
        if mod == 0:
            if quotient <= divisor:
                yield [divisor, quotient]
            for factors in get_factors_list(quotient, divisor):
                yield [divisor] + factors

def print_factors(x):
    if x > 0:
        for factors in get_factors_list(x):
            print '*'.join(map(str, factors))
    else:
        print "Enter a positive number"
```